# Angular aw-wizard default step on form load

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am using Angular version `15`
Here is my component ts file

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, Renderer2, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { BlockUI, NgBlockUI } from 'ng-block-ui';
import { NgbDateStruct, NgbTimeStruct, NgbDate } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { WizardComponent } from 'angular-archwizard';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-formwizard',
  templateUrl: './formwizard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./formwizard.component.css']
})
export class FormwizardComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {
  @BlockUI('numberTabs') blockUINumberTabs: NgBlockUI;
  @BlockUI('iconTabs') blockUIIconTabs: NgBlockUI;

  options = {
    minimize: true,
    reload: true,
    expand: true,
    close: true
  };

  @ViewChild('wizard') wizard: WizardComponent;

  @ViewChild('formButton') formButton: ElementRef;s
  
  d2: any;
  d3: any;
  d4: any;
  d5: any;
  model: NgbDateStruct;
  popupModel;
  numberTab: FormGroup;
  iconTab: FormGroup;
  verticalTab: FormGroup;

  stepOneForm: FormGroup;
  stepTwoForm: FormGroup;
  stepThreeForm: FormGroup;
  stepFourForm: FormGroup;

  displayMonthsForStep1 = 1;

  displayMonthsForStep3 = 1;
  navigation = 'select';
  showWeekNumbers = false;
  outsideDays = 'visible';
  isStepFourReached = false;
  isStepThreeReached = false;
  isStepTwoReached = false;
  isStepOneReached = false;


  countries = ['Amsterdam', 'Berlin', 'Frankfurt'];
  eventType = ['Banquet', 'Fund Raiser', 'Dinner Party', 'Wedding'];
  eventLocation = ['Amsterdam', 'Berlin', 'Frankfurt'];
  eventStatus = ['Planning', 'In Progress', 'Finished'];
  requirements1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'Staffing' }, { id: 2, name: 'Catering' }];
  requirements2 = [{ id: 3, name: 'Staffing' }, { id: 4, name: 'Catering' }];
  requirements3 = [{ id: 5, name: 'Staffing' }, { id: 6, name: 'Catering' }];
  requirements4 = [{ id: 7, name: 'Staffing' }, { id: 8, name: 'Catering' }];
  agendaItems1 = [{ id: 1, name: '1st item', idName: 'item1' }, { id: 2, name: '2st item', idName: 'item2'},
                  { id: 3, name: '3st item', idName: 'item3' }, { id: 4, name: '4st item', idName: 'item4' },
                  { id: 5, name: '5st item', idName: 'item5' }];
  agendaItems2 = [{ id: 6, name: '1st item', idName: 'item6' }, { id: 7, name: '2st item', idName: 'item7'},
                  { id: 8, name: '3st item', idName: 'item8' }, { id: 9, name: '4st item', idName: 'item9' },
                  { id: 10, name: '5st item', idName: 'item10' }];
  agendaItems3 = [{ id: 11, name: '1st item', idName: 'item11' }, { id: 12, name: '2st item', idName: 'item12'},
                  { id: 13, name: '3st item', idName: 'item13' }, { id: 14, name: '4st item', idName: 'item14' },
                  { id: 15, name: '5st item', idName: 'item15' }];
  agendaItems4 = [{ id: 16, name: '1st item', idName: 'item16' }, { id: 17, name: '2st item', idName: 'item17'},
                  { id: 18, name: '3st item', idName: 'item18' }, { id: 19, name: '4st item', idName: 'item19' },
                  { id: 20, name: '5st item', idName: 'item20' }];

  public breadcrumb: any;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  clickFormButton() {
    const buttonElement: HTMLButtonElement = this.formButton.nativeElement;
    this.renderer.selectRootElement(buttonElement).click();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Access the formButton element here
    if (this.wizard) {
      console.log('Wizard:', this.wizard);
      this.goToStep(2);
      console.log("Should be navigated.......................................to 2");
    }

    if (this.formButton) {
      console.log('formButton:', this.formButton.nativeElement);
      // Perform any further operations with the button element
      //this.clickFormButton();
      //this.wizard.goToNextStep();
    }
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.breadcrumb = {
      'mainlabel': 'Circle Style',
      'links': [
        {
          'name': 'Home',
          'isLink': true,
          'link': '/dashboard/sales'
        },
        {
          'name': 'Form Wizard',
          'isLink': true,
          'link': '#'
        },
        {
          'name': 'Form Wizard Circle Steps',
          'isLink': false
        }
      ]
    };

    this.numberTab = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      country: ['', [Validators.required]],
      phone: ['', [Validators.required]],
      birthDate1: ['', [Validators.required]],
      proposalTitle: ['', Validators.required],
      jobTitle: ['', Validators.required],
      email2: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      description: ['', [Validators.required]],
      videoURL: ['', [Validators.required]],
      eventName: ['', Validators.required],
      eventType: ['', Validators.required],
      eventLocation: ['', Validators.required],
      eventDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
      eventStatus: ['', [Validators.required]],
      requirementsArray: this.formBuilder.array(['', [Validators.required]]),
      meetingName: ['', Validators.required],
      location: ['', Validators.required],
      participantName: ['', Validators.required],
      decisionsReached: ['', Validators.required],
      agendaItems: this.formBuilder.array(['', [Validators.required]])
    });
    this.iconTab = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      country: ['', [Validators.required]],
      phone: ['', [Validators.required]],
      birthDate2: ['', [Validators.required]],
      proposalTitle: ['', Validators.required],
      jobTitle: ['', Validators.required],
      email2: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      description: ['', [Validators.required]],
      videoURL: ['', [Validators.required]],
      eventName: ['', Validators.required],
      eventType: ['', Validators.required],
      eventLocation: ['', Validators.required],
      eventDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
      eventStatus: ['', [Validators.required]],
      requirementsArray: this.formBuilder.array(['', [Validators.required]]),
      meetingName: ['', Validators.required],
      location: ['', Validators.required],
      participantName: ['', Validators.required],
      decisionsReached: ['', Validators.required],
      agendaItems: this.formBuilder.array(['', [Validators.required]])
    });

    this.verticalTab = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      country: ['', [Validators.required]],
      phone: ['', [Validators.required]],
      birthDate4: ['', [Validators.required]],
      proposalTitle: ['', Validators.required],
      jobTitle: ['', Validators.required],
      email2: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      description: ['', [Validators.required]],
      videoURL: ['', [Validators.required]],
      eventName: ['', Validators.required],
      eventType: ['', Validators.required],
      eventLocation: ['', Validators.required],
      eventDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
      eventStatus: ['', [Validators.required]],
      requirementsArray: this.formBuilder.array(['', [Validators.required]]),
      meetingName: ['', Validators.required],
      location: ['', Validators.required],
      participantName: ['', Validators.required],
      decisionsReached: ['', Validators.required],
      agendaItems: this.formBuilder.array(['', [Validators.required]])
    });

    this.stepOneForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      country: ['', [Validators.required]],
      phone: ['', [Validators.required]],
      birthDate3: ['']
    });

    this.stepTwoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      proposalTitle: ['', Validators.required],
      jobTitle: ['', Validators.required],
      email2: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      description: ['', [Validators.required]],
      videoURL: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });

    this.stepThreeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      eventName: ['', Validators.required],
      eventType: ['', Validators.required],
      eventLocation: ['', Validators.required],
      eventDate: [''],
      eventStatus: ['', [Validators.required]],
      requirementsArray: this.formBuilder.array(['', [Validators.required]])
    });

    this.stepFourForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      meetingName: ['', Validators.required],
      location: ['', Validators.required],
      participantName: ['', Validators.required],
      decisionsReached: ['', Validators.required],
      agendaItems: this.formBuilder.array(['', [Validators.required]])
    });

    //this.clickFormButton();
    // this.goToStep(2);
  }

  public previousFourthStep() {
    this.isStepFourReached = true;
  }
  get f() {
    return this.stepOneForm.controls;
  }
  get i() {
    return this.stepTwoForm.controls;
  }
  get j() {
    return this.stepThreeForm.controls;
  }
  get k() {
    return this.stepFourForm.controls;
  }
  submit() {
    window.alert('Form submitted.');
  }

  reloadNumberTabs() {
    this.blockUINumberTabs.start('Loading..');

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.blockUINumberTabs.stop();
    }, 2500);
  }

  reloadIconTabs() {
    this.blockUIIconTabs.start('Loading..');

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.blockUIIconTabs.stop();
    }, 2500);
  }

  triggerNextStep(): void {
    if (this.wizard) {
      this.wizard.goToNextStep();
    }
  }

  // Method to programmatically trigger the previous step
  triggerPreviousStep(): void {
    if (this.wizard) {
      this.wizard.goToPreviousStep();
    }
  }

  // Method to programmatically go to a specific step by index
  goToStep(index: number): void {
    if (this.wizard) {
      this.wizard.goToStep(index);
    }
  }

}
```

HTML File

```
<div class="app-content content">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content-header row mb-1">
      <app-breadcrumb class="col-12" [breadcrumb]="breadcrumb"></app-breadcrumb>
    </div>
    <div class="content-body">
      <!-- Form wizard with number tabs section start -->
      <section id="number-tabs">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12" *blockUI="'numberTabs'; message: 'Loading'">
            <m-card [options]="options" (reloadFunction)="reloadNumberTabs($event)">
              <ng-container mCardHeaderTitle>
                Reactive form wizard with number tabs
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container mCardBody>
                <div class="card-block">
                  <aw-wizard #wizard navBarLayout="large-filled-symbols" >
                    <aw-wizard-step [stepTitle]="'Step 1'" [navigationSymbol]="{ symbol: '1'}">
                      <form [formGroup]="numberTab">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class='col-md-6'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="form-control-label" for="firstname">First Name :</label>
                              <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="firstName" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="form-control-label" for="email">Email Address :</label>
                              <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="email" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="form-control-label" for="phone">Phone Number :</label>
                              <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="phone" />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class='col-md-6'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="form-control-label" for="lastname">Last Name :</label>
                              <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="lastName" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="form-control-label" for="city">Select City :</label>
                              <select class="form-control input-md" formControlName="country">
                                <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">{{country}}</option>
                              </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="form-control-label" for="jobTitle">Date of Birth :</label>
                              <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp"
                                ngbDatepicker #d2="ngbDatepicker">
                              <div class="input-group-append">
                                <div class="input-group-text" (click)="d2.toggle()">
                                  <i class="fa fa-calendar" style="cursor: pointer;"></i>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-center">
                          <button type="button" uiSref="work" class="btn btn-info btn-raised"
                            [disabled]="numberTab.valid" awNextStep id="form-1" #formButton>
                            Next
                            <span style="margin-left:10px;">
                              <i class="feather ft-chevron-right"></i>
                            </span>
                          </button>
                          <button [awGoToStep]="{ stepIndex: 2 }" (finalize)="finalizeStep()">Go directly to the third Step</button>


                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </aw-wizard-step>
                    <aw-wizard-step [stepTitle]="'Step 2'" [navigationSymbol]="{ symbol: '2'}">
                      <form [formGroup]="numberTab">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class='col-md-6'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="form-control-label" for="proposal">Proposal Title :</label>
                              <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="proposalTitle" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="form-control-label" for="email">Email Address :</label>
                              <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="email2" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="form-control-label" for="videoURL">Video URL :</label>
                              <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="videoURL" />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class='col-md-6'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="form-control-label" for="jobTitle">Job Title :</label>
                              <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="jobTitle" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="form-control-label" for="description">Short Description :</label>
                              <textarea class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="description"
                                rows="3"></textarea>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-center space-20">
                          <button uiSref="personal" type="button" class="btn btn-raised btn-secondary mr-1"
                            awPreviousStep>
                            <span style="margin-right:10px;">
                              <i class="feather ft-chevron-left"></i>
                            </span> Previous</button>
                          <button uiSref="address" type="button" class="btn btn-raised btn-info"
                            [disabled]="numberTab.valid" awNextStep>
                            Next
                            <span style="margin-left:10px;">
                              <i class="feather ft-chevron-right"></i>
                            </span>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </aw-wizard-step>
                    <aw-wizard-step [stepTitle]="'Step 3'" [navigationSymbol]="{ symbol: '3'}">
                      <form [formGroup]="numberTab">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class='col-md-6'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="form-control-label" for="eventName">Event Name :</label>
                              <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="eventName" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="form-control-label" for="eventType">Event Type :</label>
                              <select class="form-control input-md" formControlName="eventType">
                                <option *ngFor="let type of eventType" [value]="type">{{type}}</option>
                              </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="form-control-label" for="eventLocation">Event Location :</label>
                              <select class="form-control input-md" formControlName="eventLocation">
                                <option *ngFor="let location of eventLocation" [value]="location">{{location}}
                                </option>
                              </select>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class='col-md-6'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="form-control-label" for="jobTitle">Event Date :</label>
                              <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" formControlName="eventDate"
                                [displayMonths]="displayMonthsForStep3" [navigation]="navigation"
                                [outsideDays]="outsideDays" [showWeekNumbers]="showWeekNumbers" ngbDatepicker
                                #d="ngbDatepicker" (click)="d.toggle()">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="form-control-label" for="eventLocation">Event Status :</label>
                              <select class="form-control input-md" formControlName="eventStatus">
                                <option *ngFor="let status of eventStatus" [value]="status">{{status}}
                                </option>
                              </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Requirements :</label>
                              <div class="c-inputs-stacked">
                                <div class="d-inline-block custom-control custom-checkbox mr-1"
                                  *ngFor="let data of requirements1">
                                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{data.name}}{{data.id}}">
                                  <label class="custom-control-label"
                                    for="{{data.name}}{{data.id}}">{{data.name}}</label>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-center space-20">
                          <button uiSref="personal" type="button" class="btn btn-raised btn-secondary mr-1"
                            awPreviousStep>
                            <span style="margin-right:10px;">
                              <i class="feather ft-chevron-left"></i>
                            </span> Previous</button>
                          <button uiSref="address" type="button" class="btn btn-raised btn-info"
                            [disabled]="numberTab.valid" awNextStep>
                            Next
                            <span style="margin-left:10px;">
                              <i class="feather ft-chevron-right"></i>
                            </span>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </aw-wizard-step>
                    <aw-wizard-step  [stepTitle]="'Step 4'" [navigationSymbol]="{ symbol: '4'}">
                      <form [formGroup]="numberTab">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class='col-md-6'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="form-control-label" for="meetingName">Name of Meeting :</label>
                              <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="meetingName" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="form-control-label" for="location">Location :</label>
                              <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="location" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="form-control-label" for="participantName">Names of Participants :</label>
                              <textarea class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="participantName"
                                rows="3"></textarea>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class='col-md-6'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="form-control-label" for="decisionsReached">Decisions Reached :</label>
                              <textarea class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="decisionsReached"
                                rows="3"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Agenda Items :</label>
                              <div class="c-inputs-stacked">
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" *ngFor="let data of agendaItems1">
                                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{data.idName}}{{data.id}}">
                                  <label class="custom-control-label"
                                    for="{{data.idName}}{{data.id}}">{{data.name}}</label>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-center space-20">
                          <button uiSref="personal" type="button" class="btn btn-raised btn-secondary mr-1"
                            awPreviousStep (click)="previousFourthStep()">
                            <span style="margin-right:10px;">
                              <i class="feather ft-chevron-left"></i>
                            </span> Previous3333</button>
                          <button uiSref="address" type="button" class="btn btn-raised btn-info"
                            [disabled]="numberTab.valid" (click)="submit()">
                            Submit
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </aw-wizard-step>
                  </aw-wizard>
                </div>
              </ng-container>
            </m-card>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- Form wizard with number tabs section end -->


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried many ways after DOM load apply button click, default navigation all are failed, I am trying to load default state of my form. for .e.g. previously it was saved at step-2 yesterday. now it should show me on step-2 directly. I am attaching screen shot with this.
[image]

I followed few recommendations on official NPM doc https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-archwizard/v/5.0.1 documentation even but still no luck.